# php mysql database order by

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `code`, `file` FROM `files` WHERE id >= '$idimg' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1, 8");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if (strlen($result['title']) < 12) {
        echo '<div id="recomimage5"><div id="linkstyle"><strong><a href="http://localhost/edu/1111111111111/download.php?code='. $result['code'] . ' "><img src="files/thumbs/' . $result['code'] . '/' . $result['file'] . '" alt="' . $result['title'] . '"></a></strong></div></div>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<div id="recomimage5"><div id="linkstyle"><strong><a href="http://localhost/edu/1111111111111/download.php?code='. $result['code'] . ' "><img src="files/thumbs/' . $result['code'] . '/' . $result['file'] . '" alt="' . $result['title'] . '"></a></strong></div></div>';   
    }
}
```

I order eight images from a MySQL database.

Result this query:

My id images for example is '5'

```
Results now is: '6' '7' '8' '9' '10' '11' '12' '13' // id numbers images
```

But I want a result like this - for example my images in reloaded page is '5'

```
Result must be: '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8'     // id numbers images
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the first parameter to your `LIMIT` clause? `SELECT code, file FROM files WHERE id >= '$idimg' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 8`

Comment: Example id = '5' Result: '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10' '11' '12'

Comment: u have mentioned id should be greater than or equal to 5, so it's returning right, what you are getting....change your where conditions

Comment: If you're trying to return the 4 results to the left and 3 results to the right of the id, then change your `WHERE` clause to `WHERE id >= $idimg - 4`. **Note:** This is assuming `$idimg` has been sanitized.

Comment: Is there any error? If `id` is of type varchar, you may need to cast it for substraction. `WHERE CAST(id AS UNSIGNED) >= CAST(id AS UNSIGNED) - 4`

Comment: id is int(11) no error

Comment: Why does the result have to be 1 to 8? Please explain the logic behind the numbers you want. Only then we will be able to help you.

Comment: example image id is 10. In result must be 5th image. Example image id is 100 result must be '96' '97' '98' '99' '100' '101' '102' '103' another example current show image is 33 result 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36. Current image must be middle not first one in result. That is logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html
chnage WHERE id >= $idimg - 4 and limit 0,8 as initial row is 0 not 1